# События javascript после динамического добавления контента

Tags: ajax, события, javascript

Подскажите удобный способ подвесить события на элемент после его динамического добавления. Например, после загрузки контента через `ajax`.

Мне нужно чтобы отрабатывал похожий на этот код: `$('.colorbox').colorbox();`

Т.е. мои события я привязываю через `$(document).on()`, поэтому они отрабатывают. События сторонних плагинов реализованы по другому, а потому не выполняются после динамической загрузки контента.

На данный момент использую `$(document).ajaxSuccess()` для привязки событий сторонних плагинов после загрузки контента с помощью `ajax`.

Меня интересует есть ли более элегантное решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, как можно навесить событие на динамический элемент.

Первое, это навешивание обработчика по какому-то событию, т.е.:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.element', function(){
    if($(this).data('colorbox') != undefined) {
        $('.colorbox').colorbox();
    }
});
```

Еще можно поиграться с событиями DOM: [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Events#Mutation_DOM_events).

Comment: Уже писал, что этот метод применяю, но для сторонних плагинов решение не найдено.

Comment: @alekseidolganov не видел, чтобы вы упомянули этот способ. По другому - это отлавливать изменения в DOM, и проверять измененные элементы. Но гемора добавится на порядок выше.

Comment: Остановлюсь пока на способе $(document).ajaxSuccess()

Answer (score 2):

Если на чистом JS - смотрите [addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp#table4)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery работает с элементами, которые были на странице на момент инициализации кода.

Если добавляются новые элементы - при помощи ajax'а или функций типа append() - то события не затрагивают их.

Как же работать с новыми созданными элементами DOM?

Оказывается для динамических элементов используется делегированная обработка событий.

Если кратко, то смысл делегирования в том, что обработчики "навешиваются" не на отсутствующие в dom элементы, а на существующий родительский объект.

Таким образом, при срабатывании соответствующего события , будет вызван данный обработчик для всех элементов, соответствующих селектору, даже если этих элементов не было во время объявлении обработчика (например при загрузке страницы).

[100 % рабочий пример здесь](http://www.keenself.ru/blog/jquery/sobytiya_i_dinamicheski_dobavlennye_elementy_v_jquery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте напрямую вызывать:

```
$(document).on('click', '.colorbox', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jquery live` уже устарел. 
Лучше использовать [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: смотря какую версию jquery он использует)

Comment: Использую on, но после загрузки нового контента события не выполняются, за исключением $(document).on

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.your_added_element', function(e){
    // благодаря "делегированию событий" - событие сработает всегда
})
```

Comment: Про это уже упоминал выше. Мне нужно чтобы срабатывал код типа $('.colorbox').colorbox();

Answer (score -1):

`jquery live('click', callback)` или `on('click', callback)`

Comment: Метод `live` устарел давно. Выбросите его из головы.