# jquery не видит класс checkboxList

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

У меня есть список чекбоксов районов и список чекбоксов зон. При нажатии на чекбокс района, его id передается в контроллер, а с контроллера формируется список зон из БД по этому району.

Таким обазом узнаю id района и передаю в контроллер

```
 $('.select_cities_inpt').on('change', function() {
            znach = $(this).val();
            idi = this.id;
            $.post("list?id="+znach, function( data ) {
                $("#list_city"+idi.split('select_cities_id')[1]).html( data );
            });
            //this.id - id текущего елемента. split('..)[1] - для того, чтобы получить последний символ.
        });
```

Затем метод в контроллере, которые формирует список и возвращает уже html кодом, в котором я указую класс конкретно для каждого input'a.

```
     $data = ArrayHelper::map(CityRegionsZone::find()
                ->where(['city_region_id' => $id])
                ->all()), 'id', 'name');

  foreach ($regZone as $item) {
                echo "<label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cities_list_checkbox_id\"
 class=\"cities_list_checkbox\" name=\"ClientsObjectType[0][zones_cities_all]\" value=\"".$item->id."\">".$item->name."</label>";
            }
```

И уже показую по id готовый список чекбоксов зон. Работает все верно, передает что нужно в массив POST

```
 $("#city_zone_id"+this.id.split('select_cities_id')[1]).show();
```

Теперь мне нужно навешать событие на чекбоксы зон - узнать какие value "чекнуты".

Но, когда я пишу событие на класс, тот что указал в контроллере -  `class=\"cities_list_checkbox\"`, jquery игнорирует событие.

К примеру, просто чтобы проверить ли событие -

```
$('.cities_list_checkbox').on('change', function() { 
alert('HelloWorld'); 
});
```

Но, инспектором видно, что все ок, такой класс прописан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверно, все по тому, что я формирую список с классом из контроллера, а не указываю его явно.

Что можете посоветовать в данной ситуации ??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [События javascript после динамического добавления контента](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236776/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-javascript-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, вы навешиваете событие на класс при загрузке страницы. Событие привязывается к элементам, которые уже существуют, но не знает о том, что в будущем появятся какие-то новые элементы.

Когда содержимое страницы обновляется через ajax, новые элементы не получают привязку к событию.

Попробуйте привязывать событие не к элементам с конкретным классом, а к `$(document)` с указанием селектора:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cities_list_checkbox', function() { ... })
```

В документации это называется **delegated** event handler: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Вместо document можно привязывать событие к элементу, который является общим родителем элементов, подходящих по селектору. Но к такому, который **не обновляется** через ajax.

Comment: Для отвязки обработчика в jquery используется  .off() http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили)